# How to remove subscription in AWS CloudWatch Log Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am not able to delete these subscriptions attached to the CloudWatch Logs Groups.

[image: screenshot]

These subscriptions are created by CloudFormation stack via Serverless Framework. However, when I finished testing and deployed to the template, there was a permission error during the cleanup. Hence, these subscriptions became dangled and I am not able to locate it.

Tried with CLI and seems no relevant info regarding that.

```
$ aws logs describe-log-groups --log-group-name-prefix yyy
{
    "logGroups": [
        {
            "logGroupName": "yyy",
            "creationTime": 1555604143719,
            "retentionInDays": 1,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:xxx:log-group:yyy:*",
            "storedBytes": 167385869
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Log Group using the radio button on the left of the Log Group name. Then click Actions, Remove Subscription Filter.

[image: Remove Subscription Filter]

Comment: Ah.. how can I missed it. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

Via CLI is listed in AWS document => [This link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/delete-subscription-filter.html)

Via Console UI -> [This capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJYSV.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you created the subscription with cloudformation stack via serverless, manually removing the subscription filter as [jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod) is not a best practice.
What you should do is remove the cloudwatchLog event from the lambda functions and deploy, it should remove the subscriptions.